# How to use pollyjs with React Native?

Tags: react-native, mocking, pollyjs

I'm trying to use PollyJs with my React Native app to mock `fetch` based network interactions.

But meet

```
 PollyError: [Polly] [adapter:fetch] fetch global not found.
```

Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the error is that `fetch` is not available on the `global` object which probably means that the context in which you are running this is not a browser which stands to reason because this question is about `react-native`.

So you need to make `fetch` available somehow. You can do this by attaching a `fetch` object/function to the `global` variable. You can write this yourself. Or for ease and full functionality you could use something like `node-fetch` if that will run on the platform that you're using.

Comment: there is no question how to mock `fetch`, that's clear. The question was how to use PollyJs with ReactNative